# How to populate select dropdowns on html using database data

Tags: php, html, mysql, drop-down-menu

I'm a complete newbie with PHP/html stuff so please bear with me.
I've been trying to populate a select box using data from a myslq database and I can't get it to work, all I have is just a blank textBox.
This is what I have for now:

```
<select name="cargo">
    <?php 
        require("conectadb.php");
        $ok = conecta_db() or die ("Failure");
        $sql = mysqli_query($ok, "SELECT descCargo FROM tbcargo");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
            $c = $row['descCargo'];
            echo("<option value=\"$c\">$c</option>");                                                                   
        }   
    ?>  
</select>
```

This is my database structure for now, with all the relevant rows:

Database name: tbcargo

PkCodCargo (primary key, AUTO_INCREMENT)

descCargo (what I want to fill the dropdown with)

I've tried everything I could think of to no avail, unfortunately. 
Can someone help to point out exactly what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found out the issue. 
My file was named .html instead of .php and that's why nothing ever worked.

Hope this is able to help another newbie like myself out there

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Update the part of your code to:

```
<select name= 'cargo'>

    <?php

    require("conectadb.php");
    $ok = conecta_db() or die ("Failure");
    $sql = mysqli_query($ok, "SELECT descCargo FROM tbcargo");

    while ($rows = $sql->fetch_assoc())
    {
          echo '<option value="'.$rows['descCargo'].'">'.$rows['descCargo'].'</option>';
    }

?>

</select>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve the issue. All I get in the dropdown now is '.$rows['descCargo'].' Thanks for your response though!

Comment: @Kizo I have updated my answer, I really hope it resolves your issue.

Comment: Still facing the same issue, this version produces the same results as the last one unfortunately. Thanks for the prompt response :)

Comment: @Kizo I have just noticed, you have $row in your code while I have $rows (extra s in the end). Please remove the extra 's'.

Comment: I've found the issue, pls take a look at my answer. Thanks for all the responses  though, deeply appreciate the help!

Comment: @Kizo Yay! I am glad to learn that you were able to figure out the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution.

```
# here database details      
mysql_connect('hostname', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db('database-name');

$sql = "SELECT descCargo FROM tbcargo";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='cargo'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<option value="'. $row['descCargo'] .'">'.$row['descCargo'] .'</option>';
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: This produced the same results I'm afraid, I still receive a blank dropdown. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: **mysql_** is not the solution to anything. We tend to discourage the use of archaic, insecure, and deprecated code